# Load more script for content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using below script but it's not working for my script    want to keep limit 3 boxes after 3 boxes if user wants more he have to click load more link  i gave a live link to see i want load more for that boxes  or any new  code for load more jsut give me?

```
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <li>Thirteen</li>
    <li>Fourteen</li>
    <li>Fifteen</li>
    <li>Sixteen</li>
    <li>Seventeen</li>
    <li>Eighteen</li>
    <li>Nineteen</li>
    <li>Twenty one</li>
    <li>Twenty two</li>
    <li>Twenty three</li>
    <li>Twenty four</li>
    <li>Twenty five</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});

#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

i want to work for this but  i was not able to get

```
 <div class="row carousel-row lss">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 slide-row">
            <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide slide-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators lsse">
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150?rand=1" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150?rand=2" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150?rand=3" alt="Image">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-content">
                <h4>Example product</h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
                    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-footer">
                <span class="pull-right buttons">
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="relocateTo('jobtitle.html')"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>View Job</button>

                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

live url: [click here to see](http://projects.santabantathegreat.com/glassicam/design2/dashboard.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a quick glance I can see a couple of errors in the JS. Javascript variables are created with a `var` syntax like `var size_li = $("#myList li").size();` or `var x = 3`. Once these are created we can assign them values directly like `x = 4`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var size_li = $(".carousel-row").size();
    var x=3;
    $('.carousel-row:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('.carousel-row:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('.carousel-row').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

The `#showMore` and `#showLess` buttons need to be added to the html to trigger the click functions also, but we are now targetting `.carousel-row` to check how many rows exist.

Comment: can you see live url to see or can you give anew code to work on live url boxes

Comment: I can see your live url yes. Answer has been edited to suit your data, and add `<div id="loadMore">Click to Load More</div>` and `<style>.carousel-row {display:none; } </style>` into your html.

Comment: yes it works but when i click show less it's hiding can  we hide if the boxes more than three by default using jquery